# Spring-Boot @Bean producer with dynamic parameters

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependency-injection, qualifiers

I'm dealing with a set of similar Beans just differing for some properties, and what I'm trying to achieve is to have just a single method producing such a Bean but with the possibility to be "configured" or customized through some parameters, maybe with a custom @Qualifier annotation.
Is such a thing possible?

For example, I would like to use this @Annotation as the qualifier for autowiring the different @Beans:

```
import java.lang.annotation.ElementType;
import java.lang.annotation.Retention;
import java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy;
import java.lang.annotation.Target;

@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.PARAMETER, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Qualifier
public @interface CustomQualifier {    
    int length();
    int height();
}
```

Then have just a single method for producing the different @Beans, by reading the parameters of the annotation.

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class DynamicReportsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    @CustomQualifier // Here I do not want to set the fields' value
    public MyBean produceBean() {
        // TODO Read the fields of the @CustomQualifier
        int length;
        int height;

        return new MyBean(length, height);
    }
}
```

Then I just want to specify the fields on the injection point, e.g.:

```
@Autowired
@CustomQualifier(length=10, height=50)
private MyBean myBean;
```

How can I achieve such a thing, without having to create a method for each particular combination of the height and length values?

Comment: Would it make sense to inject a factory (the factory would be @Component) and request an implementation from the factory given a length and height? If you like I could make sketch of it?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is not the direct answer to your question. But just as a workaround, this should work.

```
@Configuration
public class DynamicReportsConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public BiFunction<Integer, Integer, MyBean> myBeanFactory() {
        return (l, h) -> produceBean(l, h); // or this::produceBean
    }

    @Bean
    public MyBean produceBean(int length, int height) {

        return new MyBean(length, height);
    }
}
```

And we can use like below

```
@Autowired
private BiFunction<Integer, Integer, MyBean> myBeanFactory;


MyBean myBean = myBeanFactory.apply(length, height);
```

Comment: That doesn't work in the declaration of `MyBean`. At that point, the factory is not yet autowired.

Comment: @daniu do you mean the `@Bean` annotation at `produceBean` should be removed? I agree!

Answer (score 0):

Spring does not support such a thing.
Actually spring uses reflection to inject dependencies. spring engine does not know your custom annotation.